# JQuery Show/Hide slow click event

Tags: jquery, html

I have implmented a JQuery Show/Hide function and the click event fires rapidly whenever I dont have an Anchor Tag.

Here is the example where this Fires normally:
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/MJc6p/

However if I change the HTML for the Anchor Tag like this it fires very slow:

```
<a href="#" class="show"><b class="atable">Show</b> table</a>
```

Do I need to change something in the JavaScript?

Comment: Both work equally fast for me (FF4.0.1). You might want to add to your fiddle to demonstrate how it gets slow.

Comment: same here. works fine on CHROME

Comment: Me too (Chorme 11 & IE9)

Comment: @JohnP you all are correct, it seems to work fine in Firefox. The issue still occurs in IE8, darn weird

Comment: @Paul It seems to work just fine in IE8 as well.

Comment: yeah. IE7, IE8, IE9, FF4, Chrome 11 all work.

Comment: @everyone thanks for checking it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its becasue you need to [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) so it doesn't goto the url

```
 $(".show").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); ....
```

Comment: thank you for that.  Im not sure why this worked fine in IE for everyone else, but your solution resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got any analytics scripts on your site? I've noticed that 'some' analytics code add event listeners to anchor tags and can cause a sluggish click response.

Comment: No I wouldnt have analytic scripts for the site.